# AngularJS SPA Application Insights Operation ID

Tags: angularjs, azure, single-page-application, azure-application-insights

In Application Insight, how does operation id update? I have an Angular JS SPA with a .Net MVC API. The issue is once a user logs in, the operation id remains the same throughout the session. It only changes when the user  starts a new session.

Can we know how/when does the operation id change? Or can we manually change the operation id on a specific business use case? Also, how would this operation id be transmitted to the API?